# With AutoMapper can the source be fully mapped to a property on the destination?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to set up an `AutoMapper` profile and am stuck trying to map from an entity into this view model:

```
public class CompositeViewModel
{
    public ContactViewModel Contact;
    public CompanyViewModel Company;
}
```

My current profile contains mappings from Contact -> ContactViewModel and Company -> CompanyViewModel which both work perfectly. But what I want to do is map a single `Contact` into this composite view model. The `Contact` class has an instance of `Company` as a property as in: `contact.Company`.

When I do:

```
var viewModel = Mapper.Map<Contact, CompositeViewModel>(contact);
```

It properly fills in `CompositeViewModel.Company` with the details in `contact.Company` but I would like all of the entities properties copied into `CompositeViewModel.Contact`.

The only solution I can see at the moment is removing the `ContactViewModel.Contact` property and flattening it out with all of the `Contact` properties that I need. But this seems like it should be unnecesasry.

If I haven't been clear enough let me know, and I will try and elaborate. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simpler would be to do something like

```
var viewModel=new viewModel
viewModel.Contact=Mapper.Map<Contact,ContactViewModel>(contact)
viewModel.Company=Mapper.Map<Company,CompanyViewModel>(contact.Company)
```

Read automapper documentation to see how customization of mapping works, in case you are not satisfied with the above approach.

Comment: Thanks Chandermani, I was thinking I might have to do something similar but was holding out hope that maybe I could do something tricky with the mapping definition of `viewModel`.

Comment: You need to think in terms of whether looking for another approach is worth spending time, when a workaround is simple.